# Using regex in is.na()

Tags: regex, r

My Data

```
aabc <- c(1:10)
bbdef <- c(11:20)
ccghj <- letters[1:10]
ddjkl <- LETTERS[11:20]
eemno <- c(NA, NA, 100, 200, 300, NA, 800, 900, NA, 400)

myDf <- data.frame(aabc, bbdef, ccghj, ddjkl, eemno)
```

Now I want to delete the rows with `NA` from a certain column (eemno).

```
 myDf[!is.na(myDf$eemno), ]
```

However, with regex it does not work.

```
myDf[!is.na(grepl("mno", names(myDf))), ]
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Both codes are different.  In the first you are looking at the rows for any `NA`.  In the second, it is just looking at the column names.

Comment: @akrun I kind of have to look at cnames since I want all the `NA within that column?!

Comment: `grepl("mno", names(myDf))` is a logical vector and not a column of the data.frame.

Comment: Ohh, okay, I understand what you meant.  I think it won't work in that way. `myDf[!is.na(myDf[,grep("mno", names(myDf))]),]`

Comment: @akrun oh gosh. of course. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to subset the rows based on `grep` would be to subset the column and then use `is.na` on that to subset the rows.

```
myDf[!is.na(myDf[,grep("mno", names(myDf))]),]
```